# Thicken the accent marks for OCR

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using an image for text extraction using Tesseract.

[image: Example image showing vary faint diacritics]

The accent marks in some words are so thin and broken (ex: the left side of '^' in word 'Bội' seems very dim) that cause some inaccuracies in the text output('Bội'->'Bủi'). Is there any library that can improve this condition or is there  any algorithm that iterates through every pixel of the images and set them to the same pixel color value ?

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is easily accomplished, yes, but it will likely cause issues elsewhere.  For example, [eroding a 3x3 kernel creates](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html):

[image: Original image with 3x3 kernel applied]

Which can [be threasholded at 252](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) to produce:

[image: previous image threasholded]

Note how the 9 and 6 in the phone number are now merging into a single blob.

As far as the specific library to accomplish such things, look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/quickstart.html) or any other CV library.

Comment: Can i somehow reverse doing it by converting text in bold font into regular font(at least make it appear that way) ?

Comment: After erosion, you could do a blob filter to isolate the small diacritics and then overlay them on the original image.  You cannot reverse erosion, though - it is lossy.